# Trying to add a 3d subplot to a matplotlib figure

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, mplot3d

So I'm trying to create a figure that presents a 3d plot from data points, along with the plots 3 projections in 3 other subplots. I can add the subplots for the projections with no problems, but when I try to place the 3 dimensional plot into the figure things backfire.

here's my code:

```
def plotAll(data):
    fig = plt.figure()
    plot_3d = fig.add_subplot(221)
    ax = Axes3D(plot_3d)  
    for i,traj in enumerate(data.values()):
        ax.plot3D([traj[0][-1]],[traj[1][-1]],[traj[2][-1]],".",color=[0.91,0.39,0.046])    
    #plot_12v13 = fig.add_subplot(222)
    #plot_projections(data,0,1)
    #plot_13v14 = fig.add_subplot(223)
    #plot_projections(data,1,2)
    #plot_12v14 = fig.add_subplot(224)
    #plot_projections(data,0,2)
    #plt.plot()
```

which throws back:
    'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'transFigure'

I'm using matplotlib 0.99.3, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I was searching for a way to create my 3D-plots with the nice `fig, axes = plt.subplots(...)` shortcut, but since I just browsed [Matplotlib's mplot3d tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), I want to share a quote from the top of this site.

> *New in version 1.0.0: This approach is the preferred method of creating a 3D axes.*
>
> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
> fig = plt.figure()
> ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
> ```
>
> #### Note
>
> Prior to version 1.0.0, the method of creating a 3D axes was different. For those using older versions of matplotlib, change ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') to ax = Axes3D(fig).

So if you have to use the <1.0.0 version of Matplotlib, this should be taken into account.

Comment: It should be emphasized that the line "from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D" is necessary, even though you never directly use Axes3D. Without that import, add_subplot(111, projection='3d') will fail, saying that the projection '3d' is not recognized. Using "import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d" instead also works.

Comment: The method in the tutorial is to use `fig.gca(projection="3d")` (instead of `add_subplot`) which doesn't appear to work. But your method does. Maybe it's just that I'm using an out-of-date version, but they should probably update the examples!

Comment: I think the `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D` is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 19):

If you would like to use `plt.subplots` instead of `plt.subplot` (see the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214971/14598633)), then you can do something like this one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm # for a scatter plot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,10),subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))

sc1 = ax[0].scatter(x,y,z, c = true, cmap=cm.jet)
ax[0].set_title('True solution')

sc2 = ax[1].scatter(x,y,z c = y_pred, cmap=cm.jet)
ax[1].set_title('Predicted Solution')
```

Well, I don't know how to set individual axes as 3D using `plt.subplots`. It would be helpful if someone could comment down.

Comment: Please note the additional use of subplot_kw! This might be the parameter "you" are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The preferred way of creating an 3D axis is giving the `projection` keyword:

```
def plotAll(data):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='3d')
    for i,traj in enumerate(data.values()):
        ax.plot3D([traj[0][-1]],[traj[1][-1]],[traj[2][-1]],".",color=[0.91,0.39,0.046])    
    plot_12v13 = fig.add_subplot(222)
    plot_projections(data,0,1)
    plot_13v14 = fig.add_subplot(223)
    plot_projections(data,1,2)
    plot_12v14 = fig.add_subplot(224)
    plot_projections(data,0,2)
    plt.plot()
```

Unfortunately, you didn't supply a working example with suitable data, so I couldn't test the code. Also, I would recommend updating to a newer version of matplotlib.