# How to plot a 2D contour plot and a 3D surface plot side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

[I want these two plots to appear side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XSq5.jpg)

I am using this code.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
cs = ax.contour(W, B, contour_cost, levels=50) 
ax.plot(model_1.w_hist, model_1.b_hist, color='magenta')
ax.scatter(model_1.w_hist, model_1.b_hist, marker='*', s=40, c='red')
ax.set_xlabel('w')
ax.set_ylabel('b')

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax2.plot_surface(W, B, contour_cost, cmap='plasma')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)`
will set up your subplots side by side.

`ax[0,0]` or `ax[0,1]` will refer to your different subplots.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you need to use

`ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)`

and

`ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, projection = '3d')`

before you call the `scatter` or `plot_surface` functions, respectively. At the moment your `fig2` and `ax2` are not related to the subplot you initialized in the first part. Also, note that `subplot(1,1)` would only make a single 1x1 grid of subplots, not 1x2 as you requested.

The [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/subplot3d.html) has a nice example of 3D subplots

Another related StackOverflow answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510678/trying-to-add-a-3d-subplot-to-a-matplotlib-figure)